# How do I change the number of cards displayed in row

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

- I am new to react and bootstrap. I am using react card bootstrap to generate a card layout and add buttons to it. I am able to change the height and width of the cards and apply padding also.
- I am not getting any reference where should I change the number of cards displayed in a row.
- `CardUI.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import './card-style.css';

const Card = props =>{
    return(
        <div className="card text-center shadow">
            <div className="overflow">
                <img src={props.imgsrc} alt="Image 1" className="card-img-top"/>
            </div>
            <div className="card-body text-dark">
                <h4 className="card-title">{props.title}</h4>
                <h4 className="card-text">{props.text}</h4>
                <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline-success">Click here to know more !</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Card;
```

- `Cards.jsx`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Card from './CardUI';

import img2 from '../assets/img2.jpg';

class Cards extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container-fluid d-flix justify-content-center">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-4">
                        <Card imgsrc={img2} title="Vet" text="All types of vets for your pets"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-4">
                        <Card imgsrc={img2} title="Trainer" text="All types of trainer for your pets"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-4">
                        <Card imgsrc={img2} title="Hostel" text="Home like hostels for your pets"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-4">
                        <Card imgsrc={img2} title="Salon" text="Perfetc salon for your pets"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-4">
                        <Card imgsrc={img2} title="Events" text="Events for your pets"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-4">
                        <Card imgsrc={img2} title="More" text="Checkout some more interesting activites for your pets"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Cards;
```

- The layout I am getting now
  [image]

Comment: Take a look at [bootstrap's grid documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div className="col-md-3">
```

you will have 4 items per row

```
<div className="col-md-6">
```

you will have 2 items per row

and so on . take a look at

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: How do I decrease the width between them if they are 3 items in a row ?

Comment: you can add padding in your card 's style :D

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the className="**col-md-4**"

If you set **col-md-3** in the row will be 4 items. 
If you set **col-md-6** in the row will be 2 items.

See DOCS of bootstrap grid system: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/